# Mongo selecting the wrong index

Tags: mongodb

I'm using mongo db 2.6.9.
I created 2 indexes on a collection and i don`t understand the reson that the query planer allways selects the wrong index.

I would like to understand what I'm missing.

First Index:

```
{
   "TimeStamp":1,
   "A":1,
   "B":1,
}
```

Second Index:

```
{
   "TimeStamp":1,
   "A":1,
   "C":1,
}
```

When I'm useing the following query the planner selects the first index:

```
db.collection.find({"TimeStamp":{ "$gte" : ISODate("2015-04-14T00:00:00Z"), "$lt" : ISODate("2015-04-15T00:00:00Z") },"C":2137,"A":1}).explain()
```

explain({verbose:1}) results:

```
{
    "cursor" : "BtreeCursor IX_First",
    "isMultiKey" : false,
    "n" : 0,
    "nscannedObjects" : 0,
    "nscanned" : 0,
    "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 0,
    "nscannedAllPlans" : 0,
    "scanAndOrder" : false,
    "indexOnly" : false,
    "nYields" : 0,
    "nChunkSkips" : 0,
    "millis" : 0,
    "indexBounds" : {
            "TimeStamp" : [
                    [
                            ISODate("2015-04-14T00:00:00Z"),
                            ISODate("2015-04-15T00:00:00Z")
                    ]
            ],
            "A" : [
                    [
                            1,
                            1
                    ]
            ],
            "B" : [
                    [
                            {
                                    "$minElement" : 1
                            },
                            {
                                    "$maxElement" : 1
                            }
                    ]
            ],
    },
    "allPlans" : [
            {
                    "cursor" : "BtreeCursor IX_First",
                    "isMultiKey" : false,
                    "n" : 0,
                    "nscannedObjects" : 0,
                    "nscanned" : 0,
                    "scanAndOrder" : false,
                    "indexOnly" : false,
                    "nChunkSkips" : 0,
                    "indexBounds" : {
            "TimeStamp" : [
                    [
                            ISODate("2015-04-14T00:00:00Z"),
                            ISODate("2015-04-15T00:00:00Z")
                    ]
            ],
            "A" : [
                    [
                            1,
                            1
                    ]
            ],
            "B" : [
                    [
                            {
                                    "$minElement" : 1
                            },
                            {
                                    "$maxElement" : 1
                            }
                    ]
            ],
    },
            {
                    "cursor" : "BtreeCursor IIX_Second",
                    "isMultiKey" : false,
                    "n" : 0,
                    "nscannedObjects" : 0,
                    "nscanned" : 0,
                    "scanAndOrder" : false,
                    "indexOnly" : false,
                    "nChunkSkips" : 0,
                    "indexBounds" : {
                            "TimeStamp" : [
                                    [
                                            ISODate("2015-04-14T00:00:00Z"),
                                            ISODate("2015-04-15T00:00:00Z")
                                    ]
                            ],
                            "A" : [
                                    [
                                            1,
                                            1
                                    ]
                            ],
                            "C" : [
                                    [
                                            2137,
                                            2137
                                    ]
                            ]
                    }
            }
    ],
    "server" : "mongo2:27017",
    "filterSet" : false,
    "stats" : {
            "type" : "KEEP_MUTATIONS",
            "works" : 2,
            "yields" : 0,
            "unyields" : 0,
            "invalidates" : 0,
            "advanced" : 0,
            "needTime" : 0,
            "needFetch" : 0,
            "isEOF" : 1,
            "children" : [
                    {
                            "type" : "FETCH",
                            "works" : 1,
                            "yields" : 0,
                            "unyields" : 0,
                            "invalidates" : 0,
                            "advanced" : 0,
                            "needTime" : 0,
                            "needFetch" : 0,
                            "isEOF" : 1,
                            "alreadyHasObj" : 0,
                            "forcedFetches" : 0,
                            "matchTested" : 0,
                            "children" : [
                                    {
                                            "type" : "IXSCAN",
                                            "works" : 1,
                                            "yields" : 0,
                                            "unyields" : 0,
                                            "invalidates" : 0,
                                            "advanced" : 0,
                                            "needTime" : 0,
                                            "needFetch" : 0,
                                            "isEOF" : 1,
                                            "keyPattern" : "{ TimeStamp: 1, A: 1, B: 1}",
                                            "isMultiKey" : 0,
                                            "boundsVerbose" : "field #0['TimeStamp']: [new Date(1428969600000), new Date(1429056000000)), field #1['A']: [1.0, 1.0], field #2['B']: [MinKey, MaxKey]",
                                            "yieldMovedCursor" : 0,
                                            "dupsTested" : 0,
                                            "dupsDropped" : 0,
                                            "seenInvalidated" : 0,
                                            "matchTested" : 0,
                                            "keysExamined" : 0,
                                            "children" : [ ]
                                    }
                            ]
                    }
            ]
    }
```

}

Comment: Maybe you could post the output of explain ... or better yet (`explain({verbose:1})`);-)

Comment: Perhaps look into `hint()`?

Comment: Updated the post with the explain({verbose:1}

Comment: MongoDB picks indexes empirically - simplified, it races the indexes against each other to see who can reach 100 docs (or all results) first. Multiple indexes can fulfill the query by scanning zero documents, so the empirical test and hence choice of index mean nothing. Try it with a nontrivial amount of data.

Comment: This question is almost similar to other, and this answer might be helpful  https://stackoverflow.com/a/72159004/8730051

Answer (score 0):

That's because the order of the index fields matters in this case. Try swapping A and C:

```
db.collection.find({"TimeStamp":{ "$gte" : ISODate("2015-04-14T00:00:00Z"), "$lt" : ISODate("2015-04-15T00:00:00Z") },"A":1,"C":2137}).explain()
```