# MongoDB chooses the wrong index

Tags: mongodb

I have a MongoDB collection called `test` with the following two simple documents:

```
    {
        "first_name" : "John",
        "last_name" : "Smith",
        "age" : 25
    }
    {
        "first_name" : "James",
        "last_name" : "Bond",
        "age" : 31
    }
```

I also created the following indexes for this collection:

```
    {
        "first_name" : 1
    }
    {
        "last_name" : 1
    }
    {
        "age" : 1
    }
    {
        "first_name" : 1,
        "last_name" : 1,
        "age" : 1
    }
```

The following queries use their corresponded field index:

```
db.getCollection('test').find({first_name: 'John'});
db.getCollection('test').find({last_name: 'Smith'});
db.getCollection('test').find({age: 25});
```

But when I perform the following query:

```
db.getCollection('test').find({first_name: 'John', last_name: 'Smith', age: 25});
```

It uses the single index for the field `last_name`, instead of the compound index that includes all three fields.

[image: Screenshot of explain]

Any ideas/references on this issue?
MongoDB version: 3.0.7

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`MongoDB` query planner decides which index is the most effective for a given query (also, starting from MongoDB 2.6 it can pick up more than one). [Query planner documentation](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/query-plans/) explanes it in detail.

If you want it to pick up your 3-keys compound index for the last query, you have two options:

1. Make this decision result in faster query execution time. Basically, you need a few orders of magnitude bigger documents set size than just 3 documents.
2. Use [`hint()`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.hint/) on your cursor. You need to pass index name as a parameter of `hint` method, which you can find from `collection.getIndexes()` command output.

Comment: With the basic case being *"Don't second gues the query planner unless you really know what you are doing"*. Hence in this case the planner is "smart enough" to realise loading a "3 key" index is a waste of time and space when it only needs to match and return a few things. That's the only point I would add. But otherwise the points here are pretty succinct. Bit more emphasis on **don't** use `.hint()` unless you really know what you are doing though.

Comment: Thanks for the info guys. I've actually made this simple example out of a bigger problem I faced with millions of documents. Even with a huge collection, MongoDB still chooses the wrong index resulting in a 4 times slower query. `Hint` seems to be deprecated since the latest version 3.2 and they recommend to use the shell's cursor method `hint` instead.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the **order of defining** the indexes is also effective in selecting it, for example :

```
{
    "first_name" : 1,
    "last_name" : 1,
    "age" : 1
}
{
    "first_name" : 1
}
{
    "last_name" : 1
}
{
    "age" : 1
}
```

also you can use [Partial Indexes](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/index-partial/#partial-indexes)